# Missing Schema: Invalid URL 'employee.requests.get': No schema supplied error

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, patch

I am currently learning Python and unittest, mock and patch.

Copying example from teacher who gets this code to work just fine.

What am I doing wrong?

BTW, using an Android app version of Python called "Pydroid3".

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please read [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Unable to add code successfully.  Python code won't paste correctly due to coding errors in your {} and Ctrl-K code.

Comment: No idea what you are talking about. Select the code in the editor, type ctrl-c to copy it, then switch to question you're writing / editing, then type ctrl-v.